# Comprobar si un número es entero en ES5 y en ES6 (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Para verificar si un número es de tipo entero en JavaScript **(ES5 o inferior)**, podemos utilizar el siguiente código:

```js
let numero = 90.9
let response = (numero % 1 === 0) ? true : false

console.log(response)
```

> Donde como se puede observar al utilizar el operador del módulo, va a
>   verificar si al dividir el número entre 1, el restante es 0; en caso
>   de ser cierta dicha afirmación se sobre entiende que el número es de
>   tipo entero; en caso contrario no lo es.

¿Cómo se puede trabajar esto dentro de ES6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

desde ES3 también está la forma:

```js
  
var numero = 90.9;
var response = (~~numero === numero);
 
console.log(response);

function esEntero(x){
  return (~~x === x);
}

console.log(
  esEntero("x"),
  esEntero("x09"),
  esEntero("9.9"),
  esEntero("9"),
  esEntero(9),
  esEntero(90.9),

);
```

Comment: alo esta genial esta respuesta pero te pregunto que significa esto `~~`

Comment: es un doble bitwise not, lo convierte en int32 descartando todo lo que sea decimal. un truco usado cuando Math.floor era lentisimo =P

Comment: genial no lo conocía gracias

Comment: cabe aclarar que por ejemplo los compiladores onda v8 (node.js) detectan esos patrones y el assembler es casi el mismo, sin diferencias de velocidad. La diferencia mas que nada se da en el NaN, ~~ es mas hardcore y si no es un numero retorna 0.

Answer (score 13):

A partir de ES6, tenemos a nuestra disposición el método: **Number.isInteger()**
el cual va a recibir o una variable o un valor directo el cual se va a encargar de verificar si es entero.

**EJEMPLO 1**

```js
    let numero = 90.9
    console.log(Number.isInteger(numero))
```

Del ejemplo anterior podemos observar que este resultado serpa **false** por que el .9 en la parte decimal provocaría al hacer una división entre 1 que el resultado saliera la misma cantidad con decimal; entonces no es entero

**EJEMPLO 2**

```js
    let numero2 = 900
    console.log(Number.isInteger(numero2))
```

Del ejemplo anterior obtendremos un resultado **true** por que al dividir entre 1 obtendría un valor sin decimales, con lo cual se puede asumir como un valor entero

**EJEMPLO 3**

```js
    let numero3 = .90
    console.log(Number.isInteger(numero3))
```

Del ejemplo anterior obtendriamos un resultado **false** por que un valor entero es antes de la parte del decimal y la parte del decimal necesita ser igual a 0, entonces este último también nos daría false

**EJEMPLO 4**

```js
    let numero = "alfa"
    console.log(Number.isInteger(numero))
```

En el ejemplo anterior, obtendremos false por que el valor pasado es una cadena de texto, aquí podriamos obtener una evaluación similar con `NaN`, del modo siguiente

```js
let numero = "alfa"

console.log(Number.isNaN(numero))
```

**EJEMPLO 5**

```js
let numero = Math.PI
console.log(Number.isInteger(numero))
```

Si el valor pasado al método es un infinito como lo es `PI()` también nos devolverá un false como resultado